# How to prove the existence of weak solutions of parabolic PDEs using Rothe's method?

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

I am reading a textbook on PDE (*Introduction to Elliptic and Parabolic Partial Differential Equations* by Z. Wu, J. Yin and C. Wang, written in Chinese) where a proof of the existence of weak solutions of heat equation by Rothe's method is given. Now I am trying to apply this method to the more general case:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(a_{ij} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right) + cu=f, \quad (x,t) \in Q_T, \quad (1) \\
&u(x,t)=0, \quad (x,t) \in \partial \Omega \times (0,T), \qquad (2) \\
&u(x,0)=u_0(x), \quad x \in \Omega, \qquad (3)
\end{align}
where $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a Lipschitz boundary, $T$ is a positive constant, $Q_T:=\Omega \times (0,T)$, $f \in L^2(Q_T)$, $u_0 \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, and there exist two positive constants $\lambda$ and $M$, such that
\begin{gather}
a_{ij}(x,t) \xi_i \xi_j \geq \lambda |\xi|^2, \quad \forall (x,t) \in Q_T, \ \forall \xi=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n, \\
\sum_{i,j=1}^n \|a_{ij}\|_{L^\infty(Q_T)}+\|c\|_{L^\infty(Q_T)} \leq M.
\end{gather}
Denote $\overset{\circ}{C^\infty}(\overline{Q_T})$ as the set of smooth funtions which vanish near the lateral boundary $\partial \Omega \times (0,T)$ and $\ \ \overset{\circ}{\vphantom{W}}\mspace{-12mu}W^{k_1,k_2}_p(Q_T)$ the closure of $\overset{\circ}{C^\infty}(\overline{Q_T})$ in the Sobolev space $W^{k_1,k_2}_p(Q_T)$. We say $u \in \ \ \overset{\circ}{\vphantom{W}}\mspace{-12mu}W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$ is a weak solution of (1)-(3), if for any $\varphi \in \ \ \overset{\circ}{\vphantom{W}}\mspace{-12mu}W^{1,0}_2(Q_T)$ there hold
\begin{equation}
\iint_{Q_T} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \varphi + \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} + cu \varphi \right) \, \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} t = \iint_{Q_T} f \varphi \, \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} t
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\gamma u(x,0)=u_0(x), \quad a.e. x \in \Omega,
\end{equation}
where $\gamma u(x,0)$ means the trace of $u$ on the bottom boundary $\Omega \times \{t=0\}$.

My proof is as follows, which extends the original proof step by step:

Step 1: Discretize the time variable $t$ and construct the approximate solutions $\{u^m\}$.

For each positive integer $m$ and function $w(x,t)$, denote $w^{m,l}(x):=w(x,lh)$ $(l=0,1,\dots,m)$, where $h=T/m$. For each $l$, consider the approximate equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}}{h}-\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i}\right) + c^{m,l} u^{m,l} = f^{m,l}, \quad x \in \Omega,
\end{equation}
or equivalently,
\begin{equation}
-\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{h}+c^{m,l}\right) u^{m,l} = f^{m,l}+\frac{u^{m,l-1}}{h}, \quad x \in \Omega. \quad (4)
\end{equation}
Suppose $h$ is sufficiently small, so that $1/h+c^{m,l} \geq 0$ always holds, then being aware of the fact that $u^{m,0}=u_0 \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and by using the standard theory for elliptic PDEs and mathematical induction, we deduce that there exist $u^{m,1},u^{m,2},\dots \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ which solve (4) for $l=1,2,\dots$ respectively, that is, for any $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega \left(\frac{u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}}{h} \varphi + \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} + c^{m,l} u^{m,l} \varphi \right) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_\Omega f^{m,l} \varphi \, \mathrm{d} x, \quad l=1,\dots,m. \quad (5)
\end{equation}
Now let
\begin{gather}
u^m(x,t):=\sum_{l=1}^m \chi_{m,l}(t) u^{m,l-1}(x) + \sum_{l=1}^m \chi_{m,l}(t) \eta_{m,l}(t) (u^{m,l}(x)-u^{m,l-1}(x)), \\
w^m(x,t):=\sum_{l=1}^m \chi_{m,l}(t) u^{m,l}(x), \quad f^m(x,t):=\sum_{l=1}^m \chi_{m,l}(t) f^{m,l}(x),
\end{gather}
where $\chi_{m,l}(t)$ is the indicator function of the interval $[(l-1)h,lh)$, and
\begin{equation}
\eta_{m,l}(t):=
\begin{cases}
\frac{t}{h}-(l-1), \quad t \in [(l-1)h,lh), \\
0, \quad \text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The graphs of $u^m,w^m,f^m$ are basically as follow:
[image]
for each fixed $x \in \Omega$ (the position on the vertical axis doesn't mean which one is greater or smaller)

Then by (5), for each $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega \left(\frac{\partial u^m}{\partial t} + \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial w^m}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} + c^{m,l} w^m \varphi \right) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_\Omega f^m \varphi \, \mathrm{d} x, \quad t \in [0,T].
\end{equation}

Step 2: Estimate for $u^m$.

Set $\varphi=u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}$ in (5), then we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{h} \left\|u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1} \right\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} = -\int_\Omega \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} (u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}) \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_\Omega (f^{m,l}-c^{m,l} u^{m,l}) (u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}) \, \mathrm{d} x. \quad (6)
\end{equation}
We now scrutinize each term in (6). First we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-\int_\Omega \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} (u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}) \, \mathrm{d} x =& -\int_\Omega \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_j} \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_\Omega \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^{m,l} \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial u^{m,l-1}}{\partial x_j} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
\leq& -\lambda \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \int_\Omega \sum_{i,j=1}^n M \frac{\partial u^{m,l}}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial u^{m,l-1}}{\partial x_j} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
\leq& -\lambda \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{n \varepsilon}{2} \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{nM^2}{2 \varepsilon} \|\nabla u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad (7)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon$ is a small positive number. Also we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_\Omega (f^{m,l}-c^{m,l} u^{m,l}) (u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}) \, \mathrm{d} x \leq& \frac{h}{2} (\|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+M^2 \|u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}) + \frac{1}{2h} \|u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
\leq& \frac{h}{2} \|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{\mu^2 M^2 h}{2} \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{1}{2h} \|u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad (8)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\mu>0$ is the constant in the Poincare's inequality which depends only on $n$, that is, $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \mu \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ $(\forall u \in H_0^1(\Omega))$.

Combining (6)-(8), we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{h} \left\| u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1} \right\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + (2 \lambda-\varepsilon n-\mu^2 M^2 h) \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \frac{nM^2}{\varepsilon} \|\nabla u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}. \quad (9)
\end{equation}
Dropping the first term on the left-hand-side of (9), we get
\begin{equation}
(2 \lambda-\varepsilon n-\mu^2 M^2 h) \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \frac{nM^2}{\varepsilon} \|\nabla u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}
Set $\varepsilon,h$ small enough, so that $2 \lambda-\varepsilon n-\mu^2 M^2 h>0$, and by dividing both sides by $2 \lambda-\varepsilon n-\mu^2 M^2 h$, we get
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C (\|\nabla u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}), \quad (10)
\end{equation}
where $C$ is a positive constant which depends on $n,\lambda,M,\varepsilon,h$.

Iterate (10) by $l$ times, and we get
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \left( \|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \sum_{k=1}^l \|f^{m,k}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \right) \leq C \left( \|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \sum_{k=1}^m \|f^{m,k}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \right) = C ( \|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|f^m\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)} ) = C M_m, \quad l=1,\dots,m, \quad (11)
\end{equation}
where $M_m:=\|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|f^m\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)}$, and $C$ is a positive constant which depends on $n,\lambda,M,\varepsilon,h,m$.

As a simple calculation shows that
\begin{equation}
\nabla u^m=\sum_{l=1}^m \chi_{m,l} (\nabla u^{m,l-1}+\eta_{m,l} (\nabla u^{m,l}-\nabla u^{m,l-1})),
\end{equation}
we derive from (11) that
\begin{align}
\left\|\nabla u^{m}\right\|_{L^{2}\left(Q_{T}\right)}^{2} &=\sum_{l=1}^{m} \int_{0}^{T} \chi_{m, l} \int_{\Omega}\left|\left(1-\eta_{m,l}\right) \nabla u^{m,l-1}+\eta_{m,l} \nabla u^{m, l}\right|^{2} \, \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} t \\
& \leq 2 \sum_{l=1}^{m} \int_{0}^{T} \chi_{m, l}\left(\left\|\nabla u^{m, l-1}\right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\left\|\nabla u^{m, l}\right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right) \, \mathrm{d} t \\
& \leq 2 \sum_{l=1}^{m} h\left(\left\|\nabla u^{m, l-1}\right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\left\|\nabla u^{m, l}\right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right) \leq 4 T C M_m, \quad (12)
\end{align}
where $C$ is a positive constant which depends on $n,\lambda,M,\varepsilon,h,m$.

The rest of the proof in the special case of heat equation (i.e. $a_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$, $a_{ij}=0$ for $i \neq j$, and $c=0$) is basically as follows: consider the special case where $f \in C(\overline{Q_T})$, so that $\|f^m-f\|_{L^2(Q_T)} \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ (which can be proved by using the definition of Riemann integral), and therefore
\begin{equation}
\lim_{m \to \infty} M_m = \|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|f\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)},
\end{equation}
which implies that $\{M_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence, and so is $\{\|\nabla u^{m}\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)}\}_{m=1}^\infty$ according to (12). So here comes the first question, as in the special case of heat equation, the constant $C$ in (12) is independent of $m$ (actually $C=1$), this deduction is correct, however, in my proof, $C$ is dependent on $m$, therefore the boundedness of $\{M_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ doesn't imply the boundedness of $\{\|\nabla u^{m}\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)}\}_{m=1}^\infty$. Next, in the original proof, (9), which reduces to
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{h} \left\|u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}\right\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|\nabla u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad (13)
\end{equation}
is summated to get
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{h} \sum_{l=1}^m \left\|u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}\right\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + h \sum_{l=1}^m \|f^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} = \|\nabla u_0\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|f^m\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)} = M_m, \quad (14)
\end{equation}
and as a simple calculation shows that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u^m}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{h} \sum_{l=1}^m \chi_{m,l} (u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}),
\end{equation}
we get
\begin{equation}
\left\|\frac{\partial u^m}{\partial t}\right\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)} = \frac{1}{h^2} \sum_{l=1}^m h \left\|u^{m,l}-u^{m,l-1}\right\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq M_m,
\end{equation}
and therefore $\left\{\left\|\frac{\partial u^m}{\partial t}\right\|^2_{L^2(Q_T)}\right\}_{m=1}^\infty$ is bounded. In this way it is proved that $\{u^m\}$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$, and so has a subsequence which converges weakly to a function, say $u$, in $W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$. The rest is basically to prove that $u$ solves the problem (1)-(3) in weak sense and discuss the case where $f \in L^2(Q_T)$ rather than $f \in C(\overline{Q_T})$.

Then here comes the second question. The motivation of summating (13) to get (14) is to cancel out $\|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for $l=1,\dots,m$, but in my proof, the coefficient of $\|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ and $\|\nabla u^{m,l-1}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ in (9) don't equal each other, so $\|\nabla u^{m,l}\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ $(l=1,\dots,m)$ can't be cancelled out by summation.

I was stuck here and hadn't tried to extend the rest of the original proof to this more general case, so I am not sure whether I will encounter more difficulties as I step further (I think I will because the constants $C$ in my proof by far are dependent on $\varepsilon$ and $h$, which may bring some difficulties when doing approximation). But up to now I hope someone can help me to solve those two questions I raised above, or tell me where I can find any reference. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133845/how-to-prove-the-existence-of-weak-solutions-of-parabolic-pdes-using-rothes-met

Comment: I am more familiar with the related variational approach of "minimizing movements", so I don't know how to proceed precisely, but there the key is to work with the correct energy inequality. I.e. in particular you want to do everything until (11), with the norm induced by $a_{ij}$ instead of $\|\nabla u\|^2$. Only after iterating you use the elipticity once. This way the constant will not depend on $m$ (you might get an (exponential) dependence on $hm$, but that is bounded by $T$ and thus fine).

Comment: @mlk Thank you very much! Could you please explain what "the norm induced by $a_{ij}$" means? Forgive me for being stupid.

Comment: Because of the elliptic bounds $\sqrt{\sum_{ij} a_{ij} \partial_i u \partial_j u}$ behaves like an equivalent norm to $\|\nabla u\|$. So if you work with that directly you avoid all those $\lambda$ and $M$ factors that ruin your estimate. The same with $cu^2$. Of course it is made a bit more difficult by the fact that $a$ and $c$ are time-dependent, which is where some additional terms come in.

Comment: @mlk Thank you very much! I'll try it.